# How to transformt datetime string type of variable in xarray.DataArray to datetime object?

Tags: python, python-xarray, dtype

The element of variable in xarray.DataArray is the datetime string like:

```
array([b'2018-07-31T20:13:22.084Z', b'2018-07-31T20:13:22.599Z'])
```

How can I transform data type of element to datetime object?

I have tried to use

```
da.astype('datetime64',copy=False)
```

but it seems that there is a 'Z' in the end of string, so the method fails.

Comment: You should use xarray.coding.times.decode_cf to automatically convert the datetime strings to datetime objects

Answer (score 0):

The following code might help since it decodes the byte strings, converts them to datetime objects, and stores them in the list d.

```
from datetime import datetime

# Define a list of byte strings
a = [b'2018-07-31T20:13:22.084Z', b'2018-07-31T20:13:22.599Z']

# Convert the byte strings to datetime objects
d = [datetime.strptime(s.decode(), "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ") for s in a]

# Print the resulting list of datetime objects
print(d)
```

Comment: A little explanation would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xarray itself to do so like following:

```
import xarray as xr

data_array = xr.DataArray([b'2018-07-31T20:13:22.084Z', b'2018-07-31T20:13:22.599Z'])

decoded_array = xr.coding.times.decode_cf(data_array)

print(decoded_array)
```

The output will be:

```
<xarray.DataArray (dim_0: 2)>
array([Timestamp('2018-07-31 20:13:22.084000+0000', tz='UTC'),
       Timestamp('2018-07-31 20:13:22.599000+0000', tz='UTC')], dtype=object)
Dimensions without coordinates: dim_0
```

Comment: Hi, the version of my xarray is 0.17.0, and there is no xr.coding.times.decode_cf function in it, Which version are you using??

Comment: @DZN You should have xarray version 0.18.0 or newer.
For docs for newer version check this link :
[xarray.decode_cf](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.decode_cf.html)